# Referring twice to the same footnote in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

How do you refer to the same footnote twice on Microsoft Office Word 2007 or 2010?

Answer (score 50):

You're able to reference footnotes multiple times in Microsoft Word by using **cross-references**.
However, cross-references have a minor limitation – if you insert another footnote above the original one, the footnote number will update, automatically, immediately,
but the cross-reference number will not.
There are a few ways to update the cross-references in a document:

- Simply open the **Print Preview** window (and then close it).
- Select the cross-reference(s) that need to be updated (easy way: type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire document) and press <kbd>F9</kbd>.
- There are other ways, mostly using macros; see [The CyberText Newsletter](http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2008/01/25/update-fields-in-headers-and-footers).

(These work for other types of cross-reference (e.g., page numbers or section numbers) too.)

To insert a footnote and then use a cross-reference:

1. With Microsoft Word open, place the cursor where the original footnote needs to be placed
2. Select the **'References'** ribbon
3. Select the **'Insert Footnote'** button and enter the footnote information
4. Place the cursor where the second footnote needs to be placed
5. Select the **'References'** ribbon
6. Select **'Cross-reference'**
7. Under **'Reference type'** select **'Footnote'**
8. Under **'Insert reference to'** select **'Footnote number (formatted)'**
9. Under **'For which footnote'** select the appropriate footnote you need to cross reference
10. Click **'Insert'**
11. Click **'Close'**

[image: “Insert Cross-reference” dialog box]

- **Source:** [Word 2010 – Referring to the same footnote twice](http://www.itsupportguides.com/office-2010/word-2010-referring-to-the-same-footnote-twice/)

Comment: Great answer! You're not correct about Word not updating cross-references, though: **Word does update the cross-ref number**. To do this, you need to update all fields in the document. There's [various ways to do this](http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2008/01/25/update-fields-in-headers-and-footers/), but the easiest is to open "Print Preview". This will update all cross-refs to the correct numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the info onnodb. I've updated the post to include this.

Comment: Other way to update the cross-ref is to select everything and then press F9 (English version of office users ctrl+a as shortcut to select everything)

Comment: This method does not take you to the footnote, it take you to the first reference to the footnote, which is not the same.  Also, when one hovers with a mouse over the first reference to the footnote, a pop-up window displays the contents of the footnote. With the above method, one instead gets "Ctrl+Click to follow link" pop-up message instead.

Comment: Cross-reference is such a nice feature!

Comment: Excellent answer, saved me a bunch of time!