# Word 2010: using a footnote twice

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, cross-reference, footnote

I know there is already a question about footnotes but this is not what I'm looking for:
[Referring twice to the same footnote in Word](https://superuser.com/questions/295768/referring-twice-to-the-same-footnote-in-word)

I have a 2-page document. On the first page I add a footnote. On page 2 I add a cross-reference to that footnote I've created.

Now this cross-reference is added as superscripted on page 2. 
How do I also repeat that same footnote-text at the bottom of page 2?

If page 1 has footnote: ***Test**
then I want also ***Test**  on page 2 when I cross-reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I've got this right, but it looks like you want two footnotes that are the same on two pages with one cross-reference to each on the second page? There may be other ways to do it, but here's a quick fix. On the Reference tab in the Footnotes area, click the expand button to open the Footnote and Endnote dialog box. Set Numbering to Restart each page, or choose a symbol. Insert the footnote on the first page and type your footnote text. Then insert another footnote on the second page and enter the same text again.

Comment: hmm still looking for a better solution

Comment: @juFo, Out of interest, what have you tried so far?

Comment: using footnotes, endnotes, cross-references, comments, regular text with superscript, footer text, some macro that I found on the web,  (mark entry/inset citation but these cannot be manipulated in that way).

I want a way to add 'remarks' to a document. I only have 3 different remarks, and if I use one or more (the same) of them on a page the explanation should be added at the bottom of the page. 
I guess there is no such thing in Word, not even in 2013.